# How to do weekdayText from ArrayList to the setText?

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist

I try to get the "weekdayText" from google places Api, I use in retrofit, this is my serializeNam from class: Trip, that I have serializeNam to object and getter and setter:

```
@SerializedName("weekday_text")
@Expose
public List<Object> weekdayText = new ArrayList<Object>();

public List<Object> getWeekdayText() {
    return weekdayText;
}

public void setWeekdayText(List<Object> weekdayText) {
    this.weekdayText = weekdayText;

}
```

so now I put the "weekdayText" in setText, on another class: TripDetails, my code to use this is:

```
private void UpdateUI(Trip trip) {
 mTextViewWeekday.setText(trip.getWeekdayText()+"");
```

when I use in breakpoint I get:

weekdayText = {ArrayList@6260} size =0;

what I should do to solve it? please help me :)..
Thanks alot!

Comment: what is the type of `trip`? where is the definitions of `getWeekdayTest()`?

Comment: Please share the Json object for same

Comment: @Alok this is my Json https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&key=MyKey, and this us the object from Json:    opening_hours: {
open_now: false,
weekday_text: [ ]
},

Comment: @joao86 the trip is the name of the class that have all the object from json and this class have the @SerializedName("weekday_text").

Comment: where are you setting the weekday text? all we see is a list, a settext. please add more code

Comment: @DroiDev I add to my question another code..

Comment: you are obviously not setting it correctly.... and the code you are showing is not showing much. a list should not be used in this manner. you should have a model ... a list of plans. not a list of Object.

Comment: @DroiDev I have a model of object something like Id, phots and etc, that work for me, but the "weekdayText", it not work. what I should do? I don't know how to use in this object with ArrayList.. and I try a very a lot of thing.. :(

Comment: @DroiDev you can give me please example for that, how I can see and use this? I very appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example in Java....

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ModelExample {
        
        String weekdayText;
        
        public ModelExample(String weekdayText) {
            this.weekdayText = weekdayText;
        }
        
        public void setWeekdayText(String weekdayText){
            this.weekdayText = weekdayText;
        }
        
        public String getWeekdayText() {
            return this.weekdayText;
        }


    


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          List<ModelExample> model = new ArrayList<ModelExample>();
          model.add(new ModelExample("Monday"));
          model.add(new ModelExample("Tuesday"));
          model.add(new ModelExample("Wednesday"));
          model.add(new ModelExample("Thursday"));
          model.add(new ModelExample("Friday"));
          model.add(new ModelExample("Saturday"));
          model.add(new ModelExample("Sunday"));
          
          System.out.println(model.size());
          
          for (int i = 0; i < model.size(); i++) {
              System.out.println(model.get(i).getWeekdayText());
          }

    }

}
```

The output will be the following.

> 7
>
> Monday
>
> Tuesday
>
> Wednesday
>
> Thursday
>
> Friday
>
> Saturday
>
> Sunday